# Writing additional tests

Tags: unit-testing, jasmine, tdd

[Link to the problem](https://www.freecodecamp.com/challenges/exact-change#?solution=%0Afunction%20checkCashRegister(price%2C%20cash%2C%20cid)%20%7B%0A%20%20var%20change%3B%0A%20%20%2F%2F%20Here%20is%20your%20change%2C%20ma'am.%0A%20%20return%20change%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A%2F%2F%20Example%20cash-in-drawer%20array%3A%0A%2F%2F%20%5B%5B%22PENNY%22%2C%201.01%5D%2C%0A%2F%2F%20%5B%22NICKEL%22%2C%202.05%5D%2C%0A%2F%2F%20%5B%22DIME%22%2C%203.10%5D%2C%0A%2F%2F%20%5B%22QUARTER%22%2C%204.25%5D%2C%0A%2F%2F%20%5B%22ONE%22%2C%2090.00%5D%2C%0A%2F%2F%20%5B%22FIVE%22%2C%2055.00%5D%2C%0A%2F%2F%20%5B%22TEN%22%2C%2020.00%5D%2C%0A%2F%2F%20%5B%22TWENTY%22%2C%2060.00%5D%2C%0A%2F%2F%20%5B%22ONE%20HUNDRED%22%2C%20100.00%5D%5D%0A%0AcheckCashRegister(19.50%2C%2020.00%2C%20%5B%5B%22PENNY%22%2C%201.01%5D%2C%20%5B%22NICKEL%22%2C%202.05%5D%2C%20%5B%22DIME%22%2C%203.10%5D%2C%20%5B%22QUARTER%22%2C%204.25%5D%2C%20%5B%22ONE%22%2C%2090.00%5D%2C%20%5B%22FIVE%22%2C%2055.00%5D%2C%20%5B%22TEN%22%2C%2020.00%5D%2C%20%5B%22TWENTY%22%2C%2060.00%5D%2C%20%5B%22ONE%20HUNDRED%22%2C%20100.00%5D%5D)%3B%0A)
I am just curious what additional tests might be of value other than the tests written for this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Cash tendered is less than the price.
- money value(s) formatted differently, w/out cents for a whole dollar amount,
- Cash in drawer is insufficient for change due.
- Price and Cash are the same.
- A drawer full of only pennies ( enough for exact change ) sounds like a fun test.

The problem requirements has 2 specific situations but I didn't see tests  for those; I think they're covered above.